# GraphQL indentation and syntax highlighting in emacs web-mode?

Tags: reactjs, emacs, graphql

I'm struggling to use emacs for React development, and I just can't get Graphql syntax highlighting and indentation to work in web-mode.

I know there's `graphql-mode`, but it's a major mode and it replaces the `web-mode`. So if I activate it, graphql highlighting works, but jsx and the rest stop working.

Can someone please help me to figure out how to make both jsx and graphql syntax/indentation work in emacs? Maybe share your config?

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer the question exactly but might help.

While I don't personally use emacs (I use Sublime Text) and this may or may not help but I can thoroughly recommend rainbow brackets in dealing with the syntax for GraphQL and React plus other bracket heavy languages.

Seems like you can find out more here:
**[EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters)**, and the mode itself is at **[rainbow-delimiters.el](https://raw.github.com/jlr/rainbow-delimiters/master/rainbow-delimiters.el)**.